# $(1+\frac{1}{n\log n})^n-1=O(\frac{1}{n})$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory

When I solved a problem, I could solve it if I assumed that $(1+\frac{1}{n\log n})^n-1=O(\frac{1}{n})$

I tried to prove it, but I failed.

Actually, I don't convince if it is true.

Is it correct? If so, how to solve it?

Comment: I don't think it's true either. What is "it?"

Comment: It is false.  You didn't by chance mean $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n\log n}\right)^n-1$, did you?  At least then it would converge to $0$ (but slowly).

Comment: Or maybe you mean $\left(1-\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)^n$?

Comment: sorry, I edited it.

Comment: @Ryuichi: That still converges to $1$, hence is not $O(g(n))$ for any $g(n)$ converging to $0$.

Comment: I may be confusing something...

Comment: With the new version, note that Robert Israel's answer is still suited to handle it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not true.  In fact $$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n \log n}\right)^n = \exp\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right) + O\left(\frac{1}{n \log n}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{\log n} + O\left(\frac{1}{\log(n)^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 7):

[Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) gives 
$$\left(1+{1\over n\log(n)}\right)^n\geq 1+{1\over \log(n)}. $$

Comment: how fantastic!!

Comment: I've been using Bernoulli's Inequality to good effect recently. Too bad you got to this first >8(

Comment: It's a good one to have hanging on your tool belt.

Comment: Well, I'm *disproving* the conjecture that the error is $O\left({1\over n}\right)$ and a lower bound does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_n (1\pm \frac{1}{n\log n})^n=\lim_n [(1 \pm \frac{1}{n\log n})^{n\log(n)}]^\frac{1}{\log(n)}=(e^{\pm 1})^0=1 $$

Answer (score 4):

$(1+1/(n \log(n))^n$ $\to 1 $  as  $n\to\infty$.

So , $(1+1/(n \log(n))^n$ =$O(1)$$ $

Since the function doesn't converge to $0$ , we conclude that

$f(n)$$\neq O(1/n)$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  I have deleted my obsolete comments.

Comment: much clearer and elagant this last version.

Answer (score 3):

To show in an elementary way that
your expression is actually
of order $1/\log n$,
I will use this "contra-Bernoulli" inequality:

If $n$ is a positive integer and $0 < x < 1/n$ then $(1+x)^n < 1/(1-nx)$.

This is readily proved by induction in the form
$(1-nx)(1+x)^n< 1$.

Putting $x = 1/(n \log n)$, this becomes
$(1+1/(n \log n))^n < 1/(1-n/(n \log n))
= 1/(1-1/\log n)
= \log n/((\log n) - 1)
$
so 
$(1+1/(n \log n))^n - 1
< \log n/((\log n) - 1)-1
= 1/((\log n) - 1)
$.

Putting $a$ for $\log n$, this, combined with
the regular Bernoulli's inequality,
shows that, if $a > 1$ then
$1/a < (1+1/(an))^n-1 < 1/(a-1)$.